# Why sed doesn't append newline like awk?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have `example.css` which contains

```
http://www.example.com
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/
/* // http:// .cke_reset{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;background:transparent;text-decoration:none;width:auto;height:auto;vertical-
/*
*Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
*For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://zoelabs.com/license

http://www.example3.com

*Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
*For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://zoelabs.com/license
*/



http://www.example2.com
```

I already success to filter string between `/*` and `*/` with invert-match
And here is my bash output :

```
/ ZoeLabs / - [ moono ] > sed -n '/\/\*/,/\*\//!p' example.css
http://www.example.com



http://www.example2.com/ ZoeLabs / - [ moono ] >
```

I expect output will be

```
/ ZoeLabs / - [ moono ] > sed -n '/\/\*/,/\*\//!p' example.css
http://www.example.com



http://www.example2.com
/ ZoeLabs / - [ moono ] >
```

But, why `sed` doesn't append `newline` after matched pattern like `awk` do?
What should I do to append it?

Comment: The CSS file doesn't end with a newline, does it?

Comment: You cannot successfully parse C style comments with regular expressions. As a counter-example, consider `/* a comment containing a close "comment which */ is not parsed as a close"`

Comment: The awk `print` command explicitly appends the output record separator (by default, a newline) to the text being printed. See the 2nd paragraph [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators). sed does not do this

Comment: @msw: I agree with your thesis: parsing C style comments with regular expressions is an exercise in futility.  I'm not sure about your example; there are no strings within comments. `/* OK */ char str[] = "/* OK */"; /* OK */` is perhaps, a better example of code that is fiendish to parse with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed ':a;$!N;$!ba;s/\/\*[^*]*\*\([^/*][^*]*\*\|\*\)*\///g' example.css|awk '{print}'
```